# MudInput always shows first entry when using list of Enum

Tags: c#, .net-core, enums, mudblazor

I have a MudSelect which uses a list of Enums. Unfortunately it always displays the Enum with value 0 in the input field, even it is not part of the SelectedValues list. Also MultiSelectionTextFunc doesn't seem to work properly, meaning it is hidden in the markup.

```
<div class="mud-input mud-input-outlined ...">
<input class="mud-input-slot mud-input-root ..." type="**hidden**" readonly="" inputmode="text" maxlength="524288"
value="**None**">
<div class="mud-input-slot mud-input-root ..." style="display:inline" tabindex="0">**Cat**</div>
```

So if TEnum is

```
enum Animal
{
    Cat,
    Tiger
}
```

it will always display "Cat" in the select field, but it should display "None" as you can see in the markup above.

How can I use Enums correctly in MudSelect with MultiSelection?

```
public HashSet<TEnum> Values { get; set; } = Enum.GetValues<TEnum>().ToHashSet();

public Dictionary<TEnum, string> Labels { get; set; } = new Dictionary<TEnum, string>();

private List<TEnum> SelectedValues { get; set; } = new List<TEnum>();

<MudSelect
    T="TEnum"
    Margin="Margin.Dense"
    Variant="Variant.Outlined"
    MultiSelection
    SelectedValues="SelectedValues"
    SelectedValuesChanged="SelectedValuesChanged"
                    
    MultiSelectionTextFunc="FilterMultiSelectionTextFunc"
    Label="@Frontend.Common_Filters">
    @foreach(var value in Values)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="TEnum" Value="value">
            @value.ToString()
        </MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>


public void SelectedValuesChanged(IEnumerable<TEnum> selected)
{
    SelectedValues.Clear();
    SelectedValues.AddRange(selected);
}

private static string FilterMultiSelectionTextFunc(List<string> items)
{
    if (items.Count == 0)
    {
        return "None";
    }
    else if (items.Count == 1)
    {
        return items[0].ToString();
    }

    return $"{items.Count} selected";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that TEnum is not nullable. This would make sense for me if the SelectedValues was a single value and not a list, since the default value then would be 0. An empty list for me means there is no value selected. Anyway the problem can be resolved by changing TEnum to TEnum? as in:

```
private List<TEnum?> SelectedValues { get; set; } = new List<TEnum?>();

<MudSelect
    T="TEnum?"
...>
    @foreach(var value in Values)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="TEnum?" Value="value">
            @value.ToString()
        </MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>
```

Comment: does not work for me